# Thermal noise from capacitor; circuit analysis

Tags: electric-circuits, noise

I'm trying to model the thermal noise from a capacitor. The capacitor is connected directly into an amplifier with resistance $R_{A}$ and capacitance $C_{A}$. A noisy capacitor is modelled as a thermal noise source $V_{J}$ due to a frequency-dependent resistor $R_{J}= 1/\omega C_{J} \tan \delta$ ($\tan \delta$ is the loss tangent) in parallel with a perfect capacitor $C_{J}$. The circuit is:

[image: Circuit]

I want to calculate $|V_{A}/V_{J}|$.

First, I can combine $C_{J}$ and $C_{A}$ in parallel to get $C_{\text{eq}} = C_{A} + C_{J}$. Then I can combine the impedance of $C_{\text{eq}}$ in parallel with the impedance of $R_{A}$. Then the circuit is a voltage divider between $R_{J}$ and $R_{A}$, so the transfer function should be:

$$
\left|V_{A} \right|=\frac{|V_{J}|}{\sqrt{\left(1+\frac{R_{J}}{R_{A}}\right)^2 + (C_{\text{eq}}R_{J}\omega)^2}}
$$

with $V_{J} = \sqrt{4k_{B} T R_{J} \Delta f}$ at a temperature $T$. Is that right? It doesn't really agree with my data but maybe some of the measurements are wrong.

Comment: Why have you ignored the noise of the resistor $R_A$ and what is the amplifier's noise figure?

Comment: @user31748 I subtract the background noise of the amplifier so the remainder signal should just be from the capacitor

Comment: Assuming that you know the noise figure of the amplifier when you subtract the background you have to take into account that the amplifier noise contribution during the measurement now depends on the device you are measuring, i.e., $R_J, C_J$.

Comment: @user31748 I don't think I know the noise figure, so can I even do anything?

Comment: yes, you can measure it, for example, with a spectrum analyzer or with a noise meter.

Comment: @user31748 You're totally right, you can't just ignore the thermal source from the input resistor. I took it into account and now it works perfectly.